# Where to find a working version of codecampserver?

Tags: download, codecampserver

Where can I find a working copy of codecampserver? I tried downloading the source code from google project but I can not get it to work or figure out how I should get it working.

Comment: I'm sure that version probably works. You can try checking out an earlier revision and see if that works as well, but it might be better if you posted the steps you followed and what errors, if any, you receive when trying to run it.

Comment: Problem is for me that there is no database nor a solution file in that download. Just some loose files and I do not know what to do with it.

Comment: Anyone has something on this?

Answer (score 0):

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=11047&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt21

Here do you have a ready to use CodeCampServerPackage.

Comment: That also doesn't have a working database. Only some .sql scripts. Any idea how to set that up?

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer requires a login for Team City. 
It appears that the project is available here:
https://codecampserver.codeplex.com/